# Descargar audios de conversaciones de WhatsApp con la API oficial usando Python

Tags: python, api, http, flask, whatsapp

Estoy intentando hacer un script de python que me permita descargar o exportar los audios que me envíen a un número de whatsApp tan pronto como reciba el mensaje. Para lograrlo me estaba guiando de tutoriales de cómo hacer un ChatBot y apoyándome en la documentación oficial de la API WhatsApp Bussiness; sin embargo, sé que estoy haciendo algo mal porque no he logrado que se guarden, lo máximo que logré fue guardar el Mime_Type del archivo.

A continuación, dejo mi código por si alguien conoce la respuesta:

```
#ChatBot inteligente con WhatsApp en Python
from email.mime import application
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)
#CUANDO RECIBAMOS LAS PETICIONES EN ESTA RUTA
@app.route("/webhook/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def webhook_whatsapp():
    #SI HAY DATOS RECIBIDOS VIA GET
    if request.method == "GET":
        #SI EL TOKEN ES IGUAL AL QUE RECIBIMOS
        if request.args.get('hub.verify_token') == "HolaBienvenido":
            #ESCRIBIMOS EN EL NAVEGADOR EL VALOR DEL RETO RECIBIDO DESDE FACEBOOK
            return request.args.get('hub.challenge')
        else:
            #SI NO SON IGUALES RETORNAMOS UN MENSAJE DE ERROR
          return "Error de autentificacion."
    #RECIBIMOS TODOS LOS DATOS ENVIADO VIA JSON
    data=request.get_json()
    #EXTRAEMOS EL NUMERO DE TELEFONO Y EL MANSAJE
    telefonoCliente=data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['from']
    #EXTRAEMOS EL TELEFONO DEL CLIENTE
    mimeTy=data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['audio']['mime_type']
    #EXTRAEMOS EL ID DE WHATSAPP DEL ARRAY
    idAudio=data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['audio']['id']
    #EXTRAEMOS EL TIEMPO DE WHATSAPP DEL ARRAY
    timestamp=data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['messages'][0]['timestamp']
    #ESCRIBIMOS EL NUMERO DE TELEFONO Y EL MENSAJE EN EL ARCHIVO TEXTO
    #SI HAY UN MENSAJE
    if mimeTy is not None:
      #ACCEDEMOS AL REPOSITORIO DE MEDIA PARA DESCARGAR EL AUDIO
      @application.route("/", methods=["GET"])
      def descargar_audio(): 
        respuesta = request.args.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/'+ idAudio +'/') 

        if respuesta:
          #Obtengo la URL del audio
          urlAud = respuesta.json()
          urlAudio = urlAud['url']
          audioFile = request.get(urlAudio)
          f = open("audio.mp3", "wb")
          f.write(audioFile.content)
          f.close()
      #RETORNAMOS EL STATUS EN UN JSON
      return jsonify({"status": "success"}, 200)
    
#INICIAMSO FLASK
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Información relevante adicional:

- Link de la documentación oficial de la Api respecto a archivos multimedia: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#download-media
- Link de la documentación oficial de la Api respecto al formato JSON del request: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/components#messages-object
- De esta pregunta me estuve guiando para añadir la parte de descargar el audio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013835/slicing-audio-files-using-get-requests-in-python-on-elastic-beanstalk

Estoy usando la API oficial de WhatsApp y una cuenta gratuita en el servidor alwaysdata.

¡De antemano, muchas gracias!

***********************ACTUALIZACIÓN*********************************************************************************************************

Cambié un poco el código y probé por aparte este bloque de código donde descargo el archivo de audio con la Api de whatsApp y funciona:

```
import requests
import json

idAudio = '558146746341988'
base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/'
if idAudio is not None:
  
   url = base_url + idAudio + '/'
   headers = {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer EAAUtch7qmqQBAGQjepgM3ZCC5SlyWWUyBEcoZCmGyqA1kT4MuyNVnLah8pxdVBJ06qkTEaXRjhaZC68DQjPNYl7StjNcQdxR1og8tLZBBtzqt4NtvpjU2yvMoiGjcjCiof4dSAItThNQKIqG2Qx22JgseiL048avkGlJgTt7eGLyrfKsVbsuejr0D4bjKP4rI6sLeTi8ZCQZDZD'
   }
   response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
   linkMedia = response.json()['url']

   #HACEMOS UNA PETICIÓN TIPO GET PASANDO LA URL DEL ARCHIVO OBTENIDA
   archivoDesc = requests.request("GET", linkMedia, headers=headers)

   f = open("audioPrueba2.mp3", "wb")
   f.write(archivoDesc.content)
   f.close()
```

Sin embargo, cuando uno este código con la parte que me detecta cuando llega un nuevo mensaje, deja de funcionar. Creo que tiene algo que ver con que no le estoy pasando la ruta nuevamente, pero no sé cómo pasarla sin que afecte las acciones anteriores.

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que los audios de Whatsapp no estan en formato mp3,están en formato .ogg

Mira la correción:

```
import requests
import json

idAudio = '558146746341988'
base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/'
if idAudio is not None:
  
   url = base_url + idAudio + '/'
   headers = {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer EAAUtch7qmqQBAGQjepgM3ZCC5SlyWWUyBEcoZCmGyqA1kT4MuyNVnLah8pxdVBJ06qkTEaXRjhaZC68DQjPNYl7StjNcQdxR1og8tLZBBtzqt4NtvpjU2yvMoiGjcjCiof4dSAItThNQKIqG2Qx22JgseiL048avkGlJgTt7eGLyrfKsVbsuejr0D4bjKP4rI6sLeTi8ZCQZDZD'
   }
   response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
   linkMedia = response.json()['url']

   #HACEMOS UNA PETICIÓN TIPO GET PASANDO LA URL DEL ARCHIVO OBTENIDA
   archivoDesc = requests.request("GET", linkMedia, headers=headers)
   # Cambia el .mp3 por .ogg
   f = open("audioPrueba2.ogg", "wb")
   f.write(archivoDesc.content)
   f.close()
```